# how do I troubleshoot a ssh:// link that won't do anything?

Tags: ssh

I've got a link (in Chrome) that looks like in Ubuntu 11:

`ssh://deploy@ec2-snip.amazonaws.com`

When I click on it, nothing happens. I can ssh into the instance successfully. But when I click on this link, I get a dialog box for an "External Protocol Request", then I click "Launch Application" and then nada. Is there something I need to setup to get the `ssh://` links to work in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to write a script to handle the `ssh://`

Put this in ~/bin/firefox-ssh.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
address=`echo $1 | cut -d / -f 3`
port=`echo $1 | cut -d / -f 4`
if [ "$port" == "" ]; then
    port=22
fi
ssh ${address} -P ${port}
```

make it executable

```
chmod a+x ~/bin/firefox-ssh.sh
```

Then set with

```
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/ssh/command '/home/your_user/bin/firefox-ssh.sh %s' --type String
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/ssh/enabled --type Boolean true
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/ssh/needs_terminal --type Boolean true
```

Modified from [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1406752) on the ubuntu forums.

Comment: Does this answer change if I'm using chrome? I followed your steps but just changed "firefox" to "chrome". Relaunched chrome. Clicked link. Nothing.

Comment: Tried the same link in firefox and it said "Firefox doesn't know how to open this address..."

Comment: In firefox, go to about:config , Right click New -> Create Boolean -> add in `network.protocol-handler.expose.ssh = false` Firefox should then ask what application to use, try using `/usr/bin/xdg-open`

Comment: Did that, it asked me what to use, selected xdg-open, then nothing happened. Hmm. Stuck.

Comment: Nope, same result. Man this is a tough one eh? Thanks for the assist either way.

Comment: At this point - file a bug report with mozilla - http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol

Comment: Well I can't get it to work in chrome or ff so this looks like a deeper issue.